# removing redundancy in a perl hash

Tags: perl

I have a file which looks like this.

```
a_8_3_1-b_30_5_6-c_6_2_1- + b_30_5_6-
a_123_1_1- + d_144_1_7-
a_123_1_1- + c_1_4_1-
b_50_1_1- + d_144_1_7-
a_123_1_1- + c_2_1_2-
c_1_4_1- + a_123_1_1-
a_123_1_1- + a_93_1_2-
d_144_1_7- + a_123_1_1-
c_2_1_2- + a_123_1_1-
a_123_1_1- + c_2_1_2-
```

It has 2 columns in it which are separated by a '+' sign. I need to count the number of unique combinations which are present in this file.

As it is seen, a combination is formed, say between a_123_1_1- AND  c_2_1_2-, and also between c_2_1_2- + a_123_1_1-. Now I need to count the no. of occurrences of such pairs in such a file, where I know that this combination (irrespective of their relative order) occurs 3 times.

Similar is the case with a_123_1_1- AND d_144_1_7-. They occur in two combinations. Each combination appears once. Hence the cumulative count of this is = 2

I have as of now, tried taking all these lines in a hash (i.e. each line will be a key and its occurrence will be its corresponding value) and printing out the no. of occurrences using map function in PERL.

But how do I include such redundancy and resolve this issue of order among individual elements?

Please help.

Comment: Show the code that you already have.

Answer (score 5):

As always when dealing with perl *There Is More Than One Way To Do It*, but you could:

1. split each line so that it will yield a @pair of two entries
2. sort your @pair so that a unique pair will always result in the same order
3. concat the sorted @pair so that you get a string
4. store your string in a %hash and count occurrences

---

As in the below example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my %count;

for (<DATA>) { chomp;
  my $str_pair = join ':', sort split / \+ /;
  $count{$str_pair}++;
}

print STDERR Dumper \%count;

__DATA__
a_8_3_1-b_30_5_6-c_6_2_1- + b_30_5_6-
a_123_1_1- + d_144_1_7-
a_123_1_1- + c_1_4_1-
b_50_1_1- + d_144_1_7-
a_123_1_1- + c_2_1_2-
c_1_4_1- + a_123_1_1-
a_123_1_1- + a_93_1_2-
d_144_1_7- + a_123_1_1-
c_2_1_2- + a_123_1_1-
a_123_1_1- + c_2_1_2-
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a_8_3_1-b_30_5_6-c_6_2_1-:b_30_5_6-' => 1,
          'a_123_1_1-:c_2_1_2-' => 3,
          'a_123_1_1-:c_1_4_1-' => 2,
          'a_123_1_1-:a_93_1_2-' => 1,
          'b_50_1_1-:d_144_1_7-' => 1,
          'a_123_1_1-:d_144_1_7-' => 2
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my %terms;
while ( <> ) { 
    next unless my @parts = split /\s*\+\s*/;
    $terms{$_}++ foreach @parts;
}

say +( keys %terms) . ' unique terms.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thisis a one-line program to process the data you describe

```
perl -naF"/[\s+]+/" -e "$p{join ' ', sort @F}++; END{print 0+keys %p, qq( unique pairs\n)}" myfile
```

With the data in your question, this outputs

```
6 unique pairs
```

If you require anything more elaborate you will need to revert to a full program. This is the equivalent of the code above

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %pairs;

while (<>) {
  my $key = join ' ', sort split /[\s+]+/;
  $pairs{$key}++;
}

printf "%d unique pairs\n", scalar keys %pairs;
```